# Paypal variable subscription

Tags: paypal, subscription

There is a Paypal subscription mechanism which allows customers to be charged by a variable amount each month but I'm struggling to get info about it.

1. What is the mechanism known as? I can't google it because Paypal doesn't give it a consistent name. They variously refer to it as "automatic billing", "Variable amount subscriptions" and other random descriptions.
2. Is there a good source for info?
3. I created an HTML subscribe button. Can I now use the Express Checkout API to get info about the state of that subscription?

Nigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you create Recurring profiles/subscriptions using [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)
   then you can have variable amount.
2. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/
3. You cannot use ExpressCheckout API to get information of subscriptions created through normal subscription button, if you do so you will get this error `Subscription Profiles not supported by Recurring Payment APIs.`